# Find the missing number from 1..N

Tags: c

In an interview they asked me to find out the missing number from an array.
`array` will be having number from `1` to `N`.

**My Approach:**

```
   int main()
   {
      int ar[20];
      int sum = 0;

      int n;

      printf("enter numb of elements\n");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      printf("enter array numbers\n");
      for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
          scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
          sum +=ar[i];
      }

      printf("missing num=%d", ((n*(n+1))/2)-sum);
   }
```

But interviewer did not call back after first round of interview.
I don't know what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: Not related to any C issues: Maybe the interviewer expected you to search in the array and simpy didn't recognize the formula you used. ;) A few comments might be useful.

Comment: Did you try running your code? Did it work?

Comment: Better (IMO) approach is to calculate the 1..N sume *before* the loop, and subtract the encountered numbers from it in the loop. The missing one will be the resulting number. And yeah, give the interviewer some time. They might call after a while.

Comment: Surely if you're inputting `n` different numbers from 1 to n, then there won't be any number missing.

Comment: @interjay then `((n*(n+1))/2)-sum` will print `0`. Smart people.

Comment: If there's a number missing then you need to only input n-1 numbers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- The algorithm is wrong (off by one): If the array contains all numbers from 1 to N except for one missing number, then it has N-1 elements. Your code reads N elements. (Alternatively, if the array actually has N elements, then the target sum is `(N + 1) * (N + 2) / 2` (sum of numbers from 1 to N+1), not `N * (N + 1) / 2`.)
- Includes are missing (in particular, `#include <stdio.h>`). That means the calls to `printf` / `scanf` have undefined behavior.
- `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.
- None of the `scanf` calls check their return value. That means your code doesn't realize when reading input fails, producing garbage output.
- If `n` is bigger than 20, your code silently writes outside the bounds of `ar`. That's a classic buffer overflow.
- The previous point is especially unfortunate because your code doesn't even need the array. All you do with the input numbers is to add them up in `sum`, which doesn't require a separate array.
- Your formatting is inconsistent in `for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){`. Why is there no space in `for(int` and `i<n;i++){`, but there are spaces around `i = 0;`?
- Depending on how big `N` is, `n*(n+1)` could overflow.
- The last line of output produced by your code is missing its terminating newline: `printf("missing num=%d\n", ...);`

Comment: That means we need to write production quality code in interview itself :D

Comment: @KBlr I don't know if any of those points have anything to do with the interviewer not calling you back. I just told you about things I saw that are wrong with the code. :-)

Comment: @KBlr How should an interviewer ever know whether you can do better if you deliver poor quality? Of course you need to show that you can provide good quality. Maybe some comment "TODO: Add checks for scanf return value" etc. would be enough for an interview. Then at least a reader can see that you know how it should be done.